# How to fix the layout in OnConfigurationChanged when i do not want the activity to restart

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So i fixed my activity restart on changing orientation (i needed to do that for client requirement) but now i am having issues fixing the display layouts.I have tried a lot of combinations  of `layout_height` and `layout_weight` but failed.

I just need some guidance in how to fix this.

My layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- 
/*
   Session screen layout

   Copyright 2013 Thincast Technologies GmbH, Author: Martin Fleisz

   This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License, v. 2.0. 
   If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
*/
 -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/session_root_view"
    android:background="#F7FE2E"
    >

    <!-- childs are specified bottom-up so that we have a correct z-order in our final layout -->
    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView 
        android:id="@+id/extended_keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <com.freerdp.freerdpcore.presentation.ScrollView2D
        android:id="@+id/sessionScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/extended_keyboard"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="#FF0040"
        android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        >

        <com.freerdp.freerdpcore.presentation.SessionView
            android:id="@+id/sessionView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
            />

    </com.freerdp.freerdpcore.presentation.ScrollView2D>        

    <com.freerdp.freerdpcore.presentation.TouchPointerView
        android:id="@+id/touchPointerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"         
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/touch_pointer_default"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <android.widget.ZoomControls
        android:id="@+id/zoomControls"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sessionScrollView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/extended_keyboard_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"      
        />   

</RelativeLayout>
```

The relevant code which i use in `onConfigurationChanged`:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        scrollView.setLayoutParams(params);
        sessionView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER));

        scrollView.requestLayout();
        sessionView.requestLayout();
```

Screenshot when initially in Portrait:

[image]

Screenshot when in landscape:

[image]

thanks.

Comment: how do you want your layout to look like in landscape mode? or do you just want to make your app fixed portrait mode only?

Comment: i want the layout to be fully displaying the inner view (MATCH PARENT)..It should be automatically fixing its width and height but somehow thats not working

Comment: Images don't scale to fill width. You need to create an xml drawable.

Comment: it is not an image.. It is actually a custom `View`.

Answer (score 0):

your view may be filling the screen with fill_parent. But the portrait aspect ratio image will not fit in as background in landscape layout.

use a different image of landscape width and height and use it in drawable-land folder (name of the image should be same)

image from drawable-land will be automatically picked for landscape layout

Comment: what is that car background then? what is it you want to fill in landscape mode?

Comment: Its actually remote desktop in that `sessionView`

Comment: you may need to explain little more in detail on how you get the snapshot of your remote desktop. Issue is with making it fit on the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
LayoutParams p = scrollView.getLayoutParams();
LayoutParams p1 = sessionView.getLayoutParams();
DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(outMetrics);

p.width = outMetrics.widthPixels;
p.height = outMetrics.heightPixels
p1.width = outMetrics.widthPixels;
p1.height = outMetrics.heightPixels
```

Comment: It should work. Is your `onConfigurationChanged ` get Called?

Comment: Alternatively you can create a similar layout and place it in layout-land folder.

Comment: yes it does get called.I will try the `layout-land` way and get back In sha Allaah.